# Selenium - salesforce.com how to select an item in dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, click, salesforce

I need help.  I have been trying to automate selecting an item from a drop down menu.  I have try many ways but I cannot get it to work. I using Selenium 2.39  firefox.  The sample application is on https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp?d=70130000000EqoP&internal=true.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks

The Xpath is: `//*[@id='form-container']/ul/li[14]/div/div[2]/a/span[1]`

Surrounded by :

```
<div id="form-container" class="clearfix wide-fields style-placeholder">
   <div id="globalErrorMessage" style="display:none"> Please fill out the highlighted fields below </div>   
      <ul class="clearfix vertical form-ul">        
         <li class=" type-hidden">
         <li class=" type-hidden">
         <li class=" type-hidden">
         <li class=" type-hidden">
         <li class=" type-hidden">
         <li class=" type-hidden">
         <li class=" type-hidden">
         <li class=" type-text">
         <li class=" type-text">
         <li class=" type-text">
         <li class=" type-text">
         <li class=" type-text">
         <li class=" type-text">
         <li class=" type-select">
            <div class="control-container error">
            <div class="label">
            <div class="field">
               <select id="CompanyEmployees" class="selectBox" name="CompanyEmployees"  style="display: none;">
                  <a class="selectBox selectBox-dropdown" style="width: 296px; display: inline-block; -moz-user-select: none; "title="" tabindex="0">
                     <span class="selectBox-label" style="width: 262px;">Employees</span>
                     <span class="selectBox-arrow" />
                  </a>
                  <span class="form-field-error show-form-field-error">Select the number of employees</span>
               </div>
               <div class="info">
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class=" type-hidden">
         <li class=" type-hidden">
```

I have already tried using Select class but does not work.

```
     Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("CompanyEmployees")));
     select.selectByValue("250");
```

I get the following error:

....
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
...

Comment: I tried to put an image but because I am new I cannot put an image :(

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 points for you to be noted:

1. It's not a dropdown control as such. You might have to go through some basic HTML sources on how to achieve a DropDown scenario without using the actual DropDown control.
2. Escaping sequence (notice inverted commas inside the XPath expression)

Below is C# code. I'm sure you can figure out the code in the language of your choice.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"(//*[@id=""form-container""])/ul/li[14]/div/div[2]/a/span[1]")).Click(); //Click on the DropDown

Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"/html/body/ul[1]/li[4]/a")).Click(); //selects "21 - 100 Employees"
```

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work. I still cannot select an item. I'm using Java Here is what I try:    `  Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='form-container']/ul/li[14]/div/div[2]/a/span[1]")).click();
  Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/ul[1]/li[4]/a")).click();
`

Comment: Work on how to handle special characters in you code. I think the problem is with 'form-container' expression. Also, have you tried debugging line by line? After executing the first step, does your browser open the DropDown. You have to improve your debugging skills and tell us what is the exact error you are getting and at which line.

Comment: Is not giving any error is just not selecting an item.  It runs without errors.  And yes I aware of double quotes in form-container.  In Java is equivalent to  \"  but it just doesn't select the item.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code for "employees" selection:

```
public void selectEmployees(){

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

    driver.get("https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp?d=70130000000EqoP&internal=true");

    // Wait for visibility of Employees combobox and click on it to open drop-down list
    // Combo-box is selected by css locator which searches for ".selectBox" element that are preceded by "#CompanyEmployees" element
    WebElement emplyeesCombobox = driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#CompanyEmployees ~ .selectBox")));
    emplyeesCombobox.click();

    //Wait for visibility of required drop-down list item ("6 - 20 employees" in this example) and select it by clicking
    // Drop-down list item is selected by XPath locator which searches for "a" element with "6 - 20 employees" text
    WebElement itemToSelect = driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[text()='6 - 20 employees']")));
    itemToSelect.click();
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I try it in debugging mode in Eclipse, step by step,  yet I get the same result that it does not select an item from the drop down list.  No errors, everything runs. It just simply does not select the item.  It clicks on the drop down and I can see the elements but does not select one of them.

Comment: Cloud you please show Eclipse stacktrace and Exception you got?

Comment: Do you able to find element with "//a[text()='6 - 20 employees']" xpath in FireBug?